# Vue and Rollup: how to bundle a collection of components?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, rollupjs

I want to bundle a couple of components that I wrote in [Vue](https://vuejs.org). To do
so I am using [Rollup](https://rollup.org) with an `index.js` file (the file which I call [Rollup](https://rollup.org) on) that looks like this:

```
import ComponentA from './components/ComponentA'
import ComponentB from './components/ComponentB'

var myMod = {
  ComponentA: ComponentA,
  ComponentB: ComponentB
}

window.myMod = myMod
```

that then gets bundled into `main.js`.

I can include my module now in an HTML page with a normal `<script src="main.js">`  tag.

From here I can now defined components that use my modules components e.g.

```
ComponentA = myMod.ComponentA
app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: { ComponentA },
  // components: myMod, also works if I want to use all the components
  template: ` ...<ComponentA/>...`
})
```

and, until recently, this was fine for me.

I was wondering I could now use my module of components in a single file vue component outside of my module (e.g. if I want to make a site with [`vue-cli-3`](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/)).

e.g.

```
<template>...</template>
<script>
import myMod from 'main.js'
ComponentA = myMod.ComponentA
export default {
  name: 'SFCInAnotherApp',
  components: { ComponentA },
}
</script>
<style>...</style>
```

I have tried changing my `index.js` file to:

```
export default myMod
```

rather than `window.myMod`

however, now when I import my component, the module is undefined..

e.g.

```
<template>...</template>
<script>
import myMod from 'main.js'
console.log(myMod)
ComponentA = myMod.ComponentA
export default {
  name: 'SFCInAnotherApp',
  components: { ComponentA },
}
</script>
<style>...</style>

----> undefined
```

if I keep the `window.myMod = myMod` line, once the page renders (with errors from the apps trying to use myMod components), I can of course access myMod with no issue.

How do I use [rollup](https://rollup.org) to create a collection of components that I can then, from other vue projects, import via either:

```
import {componentA} from '<path-to-myMod>'
```

or

```
import myMod from '<file-with-my-mod>'
var ComponentA = myMod.ComponentA
```

In short:

Using [Rollup](https://rollup.org), how should I in my `index.js` file import my [Vue](https://vuejs.org) components and export my module so that I can use it as I currently do as well as import it into single file components?